# Reading DAT files

Tags: c++, file

I wanted to read a ".dat" file in C/C++ and used the instruction in the "[SLIC superpixel](http://ivrgwww.epfl.ch/supplementary_material/RK_SLICSuperpixels/SLIC_Windows_GUI.zip)" package as follows:

```
//------------------------------------------------------

  int width = 3872;
  int height = 2592;
  std::vector<int> labels(width*height);
  FILE* pf = fopen("../Img5882.dat", "r");
  int sz = width*height;
  int* vals = new int[sz];
  int elread = fread((void*)vals, sizeof(int), sz, pf);
  for( int j = 0; j < height; j++ )
  {
      for( int k = 0; k < width; k++ )
      {
          int i = j*width+k;
          labels[i] = vals[i];
          std::cout << labels[i] << "\n";
      }
  }
  delete [] vals;
  fclose(pf);
//------------------------------------------------------
```

The DAT file is a binary file containing the label of each pixel (as a 32 bit integer value) in raster scan order with no other characters (like spaces or commas).

It is compiled and built with no problem. However, on the 7th line (`int elread = ...`), a runtime error/segmentation fault is issued.

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Why are you casting an int* to a char*?  Should be void*.  Sorry, but this code is a mess.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not that much familiar with file input system in C. I got this code from the ReadMe file in the package in order to read the information within the DAT file.

Comment: We have no idea what "package" you keep referring to here. If you don't want to share that information, you'll need to contact whoever gave you that "package" and supplied the ReadMe file that was contained in it for help. I can create a file with any content I want and give it a .dat extension (or .abc, or even .exe or .xls) - giving it an extension doesn't mean anything necessarily.

Comment: I just thought it is not important, since I have already explained how the DAT file is created. I edited the post. Thanks.

Comment: @KenWhite & OldProgrammer, Thanks for your harsh comments instead of helping me on my first post here. I even tried to answer your irrelevant comments politely, but didn't get anything. Shame...

Comment: @user3517598: If you have additional information to add to your post (as we requested}, you should [edit] your post to include it instead of burying it in the comment clutter. Also, there were no "harsh comments"- constructive criticism made trying to help you get answers should be considered a good thing. If you take it as an insult when people try to help you, you probably shouldn't post questions here. (It's also a pretty poor idea to take an aggressive attitude toward people you're asking for free help in solving your problems; it discourages people from trying.)